# I need help identifying what I believe is a military radio

Tags: electronics, military-surplus

I'm hoping this question is okay to ask here. While this question is not strictly amateur radio related, I think this is the best community to ask.

[I'm looking for any information on this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHXwr.jpg)

Unfortunately, I have no real information on it other that the pictures I have provided.

Comment: Hmm, no RF connectors. So it's probably not a radio. It does look like a communications device of some sort. Perhaps it's an intercom / radio control unit, which would be connected to other external radios?

Comment: It could also be an encryption device that attaches to a radio.

Answer (score 2):

It's a crypto interface and crew terminal from a military radio system. It isn't useful on its own, and a lot of equipment of this nature is not legal for civilians to buy or sell. That said, this isn't the first time I've seen that exact terminal pop up in ham radio forums, so I suspect it's a model not covered by current control policies, though I can't guarantee that.

There's no RF deck, it's essentially a remote control panel for a radio that would just be an enormous green box with handles and connectors on it. The buttons around the edge of the screen are multi-function keys, and on most of these, new crypto can be pushed through the headset connector using one of several different kinds of loaders. Similar units are used on aircraft for both radio and intercom systems, but I suspect this one is from either a fixed station or a modular mobile unit, as it doesn't have a plate where it would seat in a console or the like.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like some kind of interface box to me... say land line to radio or something like that. I am just guessing mind you but this does not look like any radio I have ever seen and I have seen most of the equipment since the Viet Nam War.

Poe